# What plants grow in my bathroom? ☣

Tags: identification, indoors, fungus, mushrooms, algae

Today I investigated threads hanging from the ceiling in my bathroom, each ca. 5cm long. They started appearing in the weeks after a recent water damage in an apartment above. At first I thought they are part of the installation, but upon close inspection they look like parts of plants. I took pictures of one, with the bottom end showing something like blossoms, dead:

[image: Pictures of both ends]
(*click for a larger version*)

Small specimen, ca. 1cm long, hanging from the ceiling, and “sprouts”:

[image: Pictures of more specimen]

The apartment is in Gran Canaria, in front of the sea. The bathroom is on the inside, and it basically has no natural light.

Comment: Do you have a photo of the whole thing in one shot?

When they were initially growing, what did they look like?

Were the "blossom" parts colored when they first appeared?

Comment: @TomBrendlinger That's how I plucked them today, so don't know if the "blossom" parts were colored before. The photos show the top and bottom of the same piece. In between there is just the stalk. My bathroom is inside and so practically has no natural light.

Comment: In that case, I'd say all evidence points to a fungus rather than a plant. I can't really help much there- I know next to nothing about mushrooms. There may be a mycology forum that can help you, but I don't think there's a Stack Exchange for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is thinking this is a plant.

This is obviously a mushroom.

If you look for "black mushroom growing in bathroom" you'll find relevant results.

One of the genera is called *coprinus* but I'm not enough of a mycologist to tell if you have that or something else.